# Solving a differential equation with initial value $q(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following differential equation:

$\frac{d}{dt}q(t)+\frac{1}{RC}q(t)=\frac{1}{R}U$, where $U,R, C$ are some positive constants, with the initial value $q(0)=0$.

I tried this. First I solve the homogenous differential equation.

$\frac{d}{dt}q(t)=-\frac{1}{RC}q(t)$ dividing $q(t)$ and integrating

$\int \frac{\frac{d}{dt}q(t)}{q(t)}\, dt =-\int\frac1{RC}\, dt$

My concern with this calculation is that I can only divide by $q(t)$ when $q(t)\neq 0$. But $q(0)=0$, so this seems off, even though it should be the general method on how to solve such equations.
But when I ignore this, I still get to a point where $q(0)=0$ breaks the calculation.

So this method should not work.

Is there some nice trick?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll approach it at very opposite direction. Multiply both sides by $RCe^{RCt}$. Then...

$$
CUe^{RCt}=e^{RCt}q'(t)+RCe^{RCt}q(t)=\frac d{dt}\left(e^{RCt}q(t)\right)
$$
Then, integrate.
$$
e^{RCt}q(t)=\frac URe^{RCt}+C_0
$$
Then, put $0$ at $t$. You will get...
$$
0=q(0)=\frac UR+C_0, C_0=-\frac UR
$$
S0...
$$
q(t)=\frac UR(1-e^{-RCt})
$$
This is the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this method also has a specific name? I do not have much practice in solving differential equations. Do you know a ressource with many exercises to get more familiarity in solving techniques?

Comment: Oh, sorry @MrSnake. Obviously, there was a name for that, but I don't remember at all.

Comment: @MrSnake  This method is called method of integrating factor....  Take a look here https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/Linear.aspx